# Image is saving as .tmp file in database laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to save image using Laravel

Image is saved as tmp file in database, why so?

the image saved as C:\xampp\tmp\php50B5.tmp in the database

how can I fix this?

controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new_file_data=[
            'small_explain'=>$request->input('small_explain'),
            'title'=>$request->input('title'),
            'body'=>$request->input('body'),
            'important_body'=>$request->input('important_body'),
            'quote'=>$request->input('quote'),
            'author_quote'=>$request->input('author_quote'),
            'index_image' => $request->file('index_image'),
            'header_image' => $request->file('header_image'),
            'text_image' =>$request->file('text_image'),
        ];
        $request->file('index_image' )->store('Images');
        $request->file('header_image' )->store('Images');
        $request->file('text_image' )->store('Images');
        Article::created($new_file_data);
    }
```

model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

index.blade:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach( $article as $articles )
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%">{{ $articles->id }}</td>
                <td style="width: 20%">{{ $articles->title }}</td>
                <td style="width: 20%">{{ $articles->small_explain }}</td>
                <td style="width: 10%">>{{ $articles->index_image }}t</td>
                <td style="width: 10%">>{{ $articles->header_image }}</td>
                <td style="width: 10%">{{ $articles->text_image }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button {{--href="{{ route('$articles.edit' , ['id'=>$articles->id])}}"--}} class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <form{{-- action="{{route('$articles.destroy' ,  ['id'=>$articles->id])}}"--}} method="post">
                        {{ method_field('delete') }}
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="icon-trash "></i></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Please post the html form from where you are sending the create request.

Comment: _By default, the store method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. The file's extension will be determined by examining the file's MIME type. The path to the file will be returned by the store method so you can store the path, including the generated file name, in your database._

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$request->file('index_image' )->store('Images');
```

To this:

```
$file = $request->file('index_image');
$file->storeAs('Images', "my-cool-name." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$request->file('index_image' )` Is the path to where the image was stored on upload, which is a temp directory. When you call `->store()` that method returns the new path to where the file was stored, but you're not passing that to your create method.

This code will do what you need, all I did was move the store methods up to the new_file_data assignment

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new_file_data=[
            'small_explain'=>$request->input('small_explain'),
            'title'=>$request->input('title'),
            'body'=>$request->input('body'),
            'important_body'=>$request->input('important_body'),
            'quote'=>$request->input('quote'),
            'author_quote'=>$request->input('author_quote'),
            'index_image' => $request->file('index_image')->store('Images');,
            'header_image' => $request->file('header_image')->store('Images');,
            'text_image' =>$request->file('text_image')->store('Images');,
        ];
        Article::created($new_file_data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for someone who may have this problem for any reason.
in html:

```
<input type="file" name="photo"/>
```

in controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $info->img = $this->upload_img($request->file('photo'));
}
```

In the first, the `input` name of the image in the code was the same as the name of the image field in the database. I changed the image input name and the problem was solved. This is why "photo" is the temp file that is passed with the request. "img" has the path. See [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-is-saving-as-tmp-file-in-database-laravel)